# array is full of the last element in a file

Tags: c, arrays, file, token, element

I have a procedure readTokens() which takes a file and an array and tokenizes the file and puts the things into the array but when I access the array, it is full of the last element. why? here is my readTokens() method:

```
void
readTokens(char *fileName, char** a[])
{
FILE *fp;
char *token;
int count = 0;

fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
if (fp == 0)
    {
    fprintf(stderr,"file %s could not be opened for reading\n", fileName);
    exit(1);
    }

token = readLine(fp);
while(!feof(fp))
    {
    a[count] = token;
    ++count;
    free(token);
    token = readLine(fp);
    }

fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling free()? free() should only be called on memory you allocated.

Comment: Pretty sure this is C, but you should tag language.

Comment: sorry it is c. should I not free the token?

Comment: omg you are a life saver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not call `free(token)`, since you still have a pointer to it in `a[count]`. Since you're freeing it, that memory can be reused, and apparently it's being used when `readLine()` reads the next line. So each time you read a line, it reuses the same memory and overwrites it with the next line. As a result, all elements of `a[]` contain pointers to the same line.

`a[count] = token` doesn't make a copy of the token, it simply assigns the pointer.

This all assumes that `readLine()` uses `malloc()` to allocate the memory for the line it reads. If it doesn't, then it's even worse, since you must not call `free()` on memory that wasn't allocated with `malloc()` or `calloc()`.

It's possible that `readLine()` is just using a static array variable, which would also explain why all your lines are the same. If you don't want it to keep overwriting the token, you need to make a copy of it in `readTokens()`. It would help if you posted the definition of `readLine()`.